# Issue changing cell color in gt

Tags: gtsummary

I am trying to highlight the top four lines of the tables (One, followed by No  3 (50%) through Yes (2 33%). My actual table is bigger and I am highlighting every other variables with the corresponding levels.
I can get the variable name to highlight but cannot get the levels to highlight, and there are some instances where I might have the same text and numbers for these levels as you can see in my reprex.

```
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)
tribble(
                                 ~One, ~Two,
                                             "No",           "Yes",
                                            "Yes",           "Yes",
                                             "No",            "No",
                                        "Unknown",           "Yes",
                                             "No",           "Unknown",
                                            "Yes",           "Yes"
                                 ) %>%
  tbl_summary(digits = all_categorical() ~ 0)  %>%
      modify_header(
    update = list(stat_0 ~ md(c("**Patients**")))) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
   tab_header(
     title = md(c("**Table 5.**","Description"))) %>%
         tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#e0ecf4")),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars("label","stat_0"),
      rows = label == c("One"))) %>%
         tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#e0ecf4")),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars("label","stat_0"),
      rows = label == c("3 (50%)"))) %>%
         tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#e0ecf4")),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars("label","stat_0"),
      rows = label == c("1 (17%)"))) %>%
         tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#e0ecf4")),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars("label","stat_0"),
      rows = label == c("Yes    2 (33%)")))
```

Comment: There seems to be something off in the reprex....perhaps the first lines were cut off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code example of how to highlight every other variable from a gtsummary table.

```r
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

# build gtsummary table
tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, marker, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary()

# save vecotr of every other variable
every_other_variable <- unique(tbl$table_body$variable)[c(T, F)]
every_other_variable
#> [1] "age"   "grade"

# highlight every other row
tbl_highlighted <-
  as_gt(tbl) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = list(cell_fill(color = "#e0ecf4")),
    locations = cells_body(rows = variable %in% every_other_variable)
  )
```

[image]